# How do you give text a spacing around it in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-editors, text-formatting

is it possible to give text some kind of spacing around it in MS Word (in the way padding works in CSS)?
For instance, if I have text with a background, I want the background to extend further, so that it's no only behind the text, but looks like a box around it.

[image]

The background of this text, for example, should extend a bit more around the text, as if there was a fixed spacing around the paragraph. How do I achieve this?

I use MS Word 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to put the text into a text box or a table.

What I usually do, though, is just add a border that's the same color as the paragraph shading.

For example, if I want light blue shading and 6 points of 'padding,' I first set the shading on the **Shading** tab of the **Borders and Shading** dialog box.

[image: Shading tab of the Borders and Shading dialog box]

Then, on the **Borders** tab, I select the same light blue color as the border color and select **6 pt** as the border width.

[image: Borders tab of the Borders and Shading dialog box]

Finally, I click **Options**, and set **Top**, **Bottom**, **Left**, and **Right** to **0 pt**.

[image: Border and Shading Options dialog box]

The result is this:

[image: Paragraph shading with padding]

I could also have achieved the same thing by setting the border width to, say, **1 pt** and then setting **Top**, **Bottom**, **Left**, and **Right** to **5 pt**.